# TSQL JOIN two tables in one big table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I need to JOIN table A and table B in one big table. In each table I have (id,brand,power).

#### Table A

```
id | brand | power
-------------------  
 1 |   BMW |   500 
 2 | SKODA |   220
 3 |PORSCHE|   450
```

#### Table B

```
id | brand | power
-------------------  
 1 |    BMW|   500 
 2 |  SKODA|   220
 4 |FERRARI|   600
 5 | HUMMER|   350
```

The result should be:

```
  | A.brand | A.power | B.brand | B.power
------------------------------------------
1 | BMW     |     500 | BMW     |     500 
2 | SKODA   |     220 | SKODA   |     220
3 | PORSCHE |     450 | null    |    null
4 | null    |    null | FERRARI |     600
5 | null    |    null | HUMMER  |     350
```

Here is what I have tried but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
SELECT
A.id,A.brand,A.[power],B.brand,B.[power]
FROM A
FULL JOIN B on A.id = B.id
```

Any help?

Comment: It helps if you describe the problem better than "it doesn't seem to work".

Comment: this cannot be oracle AND mysql AND sql-server.  Which dbms vendor/product are you using?

Comment: I'm using sqlserver 2014

Comment: Why does power become -450 in the full outer join?

Comment: i missed it while editing :)

Comment: Please describe what 'doesn't seem to work' means?  No result? Error message? Too many rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a brute force, but it works for the time being:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.brand, 
       a.[power], 
       b.brand, 
       b.[power] 
FROM   a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
                    ON a.id = b.id 
UNION 
SELECT id, 
       NULL AS brand, 
       NULL AS power, 
       brand, 
       power 
FROM   b 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM   a)
```

Comment: It does the job !!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the complete sentence:

```
SELECT
A.id,A.brand,A.power,B.brand,B.power
FROM tableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB B on A.id = B.id
```

Comment: @zineddinereda What's the problem? and how did you name both tables?